# USB recognized but not available?

Tags: usb-drive

I installed Ubuntu and I'm teaching my mother to use it. Everything is going fine except that her new [USB pen drive](http://www.pqi.com.tw/product2.asp?oid=19&catE1=19&PROID=385) (8GB - fat32) is not working in Linux (but it works in Windows and Mac).

OS: Kubuntu Lucid
kernel: 2.6.32-28-generic

Before and after "**lsusb**":

```
root@desktop:/etc# lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

root@desktop:/etc# lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 3538:0901 Power Quotient International Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**dmesg**:

```
[ 1061.544029] usb 3-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
[ 1061.709572] usb 3-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[ 1061.744920] scsi5 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[ 1061.752290] usb-storage: device found at 2
[ 1061.752297] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[ 1066.753954] usb-storage: device scan complete
[ 1066.756871] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access-RBC                   PQ: 2 ANSI: 4
[ 1066.763379] scsi 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 14
```

But in "**fdisk -l**" it is not shown, and not found under /media/:

root@desktop:/etc# fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 60.0 GB, 60022480896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7297 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x90789078

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        7296    58605088+   7  Linux
```

What else can be done? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `fdisk -l` call lists your hard drive's partitions. Run `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` and post the output.

Comment: **fdisk -l /dev/sdb** report: "Unable to open /dev/sdb"

Comment: I don't really understand the automount magic, but to my limited knowledge, the problem here is that the kernel is not mapping sg3 to sd*. I don't know why or how is it supposed to do it, but maybe the comment can help someone who does.

Comment: How about **sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb**? You may need root access for fdisk.

Comment: @MestreLion: I executed the command as root... I guess it is just not fully supported (yet?) by the kernel.

Comment: Ive edited my answer to include 2 suggestions to you... did you try any of them? I dont think this is kernel related. That USB pendrive is a standard one, no reason to think it would be unsupported. Also, your **dmesg** suggests it should work fine

Comment: I have the same problem too :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you ran a kernel update without rebooting? I've had the same problem with similar messages in the `dmesg` output.

Rebooting the machine solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting the computer. I would have to keep updating the kernel and wait until it is solved.

Comment: @Lekensteyn - how do you run kernel update without rebooting ?

Comment: @Boris You cannot load an updated kernel without rebooting. You can update a kernel without rebooting, but then you should not uninstall the older kernel without rebooting first.

Answer (score 0):

Does it show up in gParted?

Also, can you check if it works using a Live Session CD in the same machine?

I will wait for this info, and we can work from there...

**EDIT**

Try to install `gnome-disk-utility` package. It will show up in the menu as `Administration -> Disk Utility` (`palimpsest` from terminal). It has some tools that GParted dont. See if the pendrive shows up there.

Btw.. can you please provide details (edit your question) as how are you accessing your mothers PC? Is it terminal (SSH) or RDP/VNC ? How did you configure it?

**EDIT**

Also, could you please post the result of:

```
ls -laR /dev/disk
```

It may give us a hint of *where* the pendrive is after plugged in. `/dev/disk/by-id` folder is the most important one. It will probably list your USB pendrive, and tell us where it is mapped to.

Comment: Thank you MestreLion, but it does not show in gParted and I think I'm unable to use a Live CD as I live in other country from where the computer is. But I appreciate your help. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @lepe: wait, is the system physically NOT in the same location as your mother's USB drive?  If that's the case, you can't mount a local flash drive to a remote system.  If that's what you're doing, STOP, because you won't get anywhere.  The system and the flash drive need to be at each other in order for you to mount it.  Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: @EvilPhoenix: the way I understood it, his mother is in a location, with Ubuntu and her pendrive, and lepe is in another country, using SSH, VNC or some other kind of remote access to try to diagnostic his mother PC. In this case, he cant boot a Live CD, because he has no access to BIOS settings or boot options. And he wouldnt be able to access it in a Live CD session. And his mother prolly has no skill to make a bootable CD and/or install and configure VNC/SSH in a live session.

Comment: Exactly.

Comment: I'm using VNC and SSH as well. I will try your new suggestions and let you know the results soon. Thank you!