# 14.04.1 installer Ubiquity crashes upon installation attempt on probook 6545b

Tags: 14.04, hp, crash, ubiquity

I have an image of 14.04.1 on a usb stick which I tried to install on an old HP probook 6545b. It boots and runs fine, however when clicking the install button, nothing happens.  Also, when trying to install directly from the start menu, it doesn't install, but again boots the life system after displaying some error for about a microsecond.

Investigating the installer's debug.txt, it shows:

```
Ubiquity 2.18.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 636, in <module>
    main(oem_config)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 620, in main
    install(args[0], query=options.query)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 242, in install
    ui = importlib.import_module('ubiquity.frontend.%s' % f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_ui.py", line 46, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
    from dbus._dbus import Bus, SystemBus, SessionBus, StarterBus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 39, in <module>
    from dbus.bus import BusConnection
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 39, in <module>
    from dbus.connection import Connection
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 37, in <module>
    from dbus.proxies import ProxyObject
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 34, in <module>
    from dbus._expat_introspect_parser import process_introspection_data
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_expat_introspect_parser.py", line 26, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1444, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1548, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1601, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1444, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1548, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1601, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 636, in <module>
    main(oem_config)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 620, in main
    install(args[0], query=options.query)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity", line 242, in install
    ui = importlib.import_module('ubiquity.frontend.%s' % f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_ui.py", line 46, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
    from dbus._dbus import Bus, SystemBus, SessionBus, StarterBus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 39, in <module>
    from dbus.bus import BusConnection
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 39, in <module>
    from dbus.connection import Connection
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 37, in <module>
    from dbus.proxies import ProxyObject
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 34, in <module>
    from dbus._expat_introspect_parser import process_introspection_data
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_expat_introspect_parser.py", line 26, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1444, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1548, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1601, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I've found a [similar issue here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511256/installing-lubuntu-14-04-1-fails-upowerd-appears-to-hang), however that seems to be connected to upowerd which I do not see in the debug log.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: How did you make this USB stick ? was it in windows ?