# Sandisk USB not detected by Ubuntu 14.04 but detected by Windows 7

Tags: usb, usb-drive, format

I have a SanDisk 16GB USB drive that is not being detected by Ubuntu 14.04 but is detected by Windows 7.

`lsusb` detects it but `sudo fdisk -l` or `blkid` doesn't.
Even GParted and Disks don't detect it.

Here's some terminal output:

#### lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0781:5576 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0021 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b070 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

#### tail -f /var/log/syslog

```
Sep 10 22:28:22 xhakz kernel: [ 2203.587319] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
Sep 10 22:28:25 xhakz kernel: [ 2206.212045] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
Sep 10 22:28:25 xhakz mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2"
Sep 10 22:28:25 xhakz kernel: [ 2206.344889] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5576
Sep 10 22:28:25 xhakz kernel: [ 2206.344895] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep 10 22:28:25 xhakz kernel: [ 2206.344897] usb 2-2: Product: Cruzer Facet
Sep 10 22:28:25 xhakz kernel: [ 2206.344900] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Sep 10 22:28:25 xhakz kernel: [ 2206.344902] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 4C532000030522108444
Sep 10 22:28:25 xhakz mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 7 was not an MTP device
```

#### usb-devices

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  7 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0781 ProdID=5576 Rev=01.26
S:  Manufacturer=SanDisk
S:  Product=Cruzer Facet
S:  SerialNumber=4C532000030522108444
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=200mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none)
```

<s>I don't know what to do anymore to get it detected and I don't want to format it as it contains important data.</s>

---

I backed up my data in another laptop, formatted the drive in Windows 7 but still it's not recognized. The funny thing is that Windows 7 detects it and uses it fine but it's not detected in Ubuntu except by the `lsusb` command. Weird.

---

### EDIT

Requested command output:

#### sudo lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   1.5G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  74.4G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0    32G  0 part /media/kagz/New Volume
├─sda5   8:5    0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0  39.4G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

#### sudo lshw

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8332788/

#### uname -a

```
Linux xhakz 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:01 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

---

### EDIT 2

Something interesting:
The USB **DOES NOT** work in guest mode but **WORKS** in live session mode. All running Ubuntu 14.04.
[Re-installing is not an option.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11710/lets-not-do-i-dont-know-how-to-fix-your-problem-so-just-reinstall)

---

### EDIT 3

Other USB's don't work, this is a problem with the system not the USB.

Comment: does `sudo lsblk` show the device? what about `sudo lshw` ?

Comment: Also, how is the drive partitioned?

Comment: @fossfreedom Both `sudo lsblk` and `sudo lshw` don't show the drive, just the hard drive. I can post the result here if you wish.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat The drive is not partitioned. I just formatted it as FAT32 on windows recently.

Comment: Weird. Fat32 should be recognized.... Please post the results. You might have just missed something (I do too all the time).

Comment: Test other USB drives and USB ports. If they work, then there is something strange with that particular drive.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat I am currently formatting it again in Windows this time from the cmd, let's see if something will come up this time. At 62%. The other USB ports don't work with this USB either though they work with the modem and an USB keyboard. I haven't tested other USB's yet, will try that and get back to you.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat Formatting didn't help. Something else though - it works in Live session mode but not in guest mode. Maybe some files got changed somewhere in the system....

Comment: Are you running a current kernel? Please include the output of `uname -a` in your question. I find it hard to believe no kernel module claims this device with the default Ubuntu kernel (`Driver=(none)`).

Comment: @gertvdijk Done.

Comment: @Parto Interesting question, +1. Do other regular USB flash drives work in the same machine/installation?

Comment: @gertvdijk Thanks. I haven't tried other USB's but I'll try one tonight and get back to you. The modem and the USB keyboard are working fine though. Even a USB mouse.

Comment: Does the USB device use encryption or password?

Comment: @totti No. Just a plain normal USB.

Comment: does you disabled usb storage

Comment: Can you test if you see the USB drive from the BIOS / UEFI setup? Just want to know something first.

Comment: @Luis How do I do that exactly? I looked at the BIOS and didn't see anything concerning a USB except booting order.

Comment: @Parto yes, if you can see it in the boot order that helps.

Comment: @Luis Well, I can't say I can see it in the boot order but the computer is refusing to boot when it's plugged in. It brings up a message 'Remove disk or other media press any key to restart' If I remove it the computer boots okay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out the `usb-storage` module was not being loaded at startup and so couldn't detect any USB drives.

To try it first, I inserted my usb, opened up the terminal and typed `sudo modprobe usb-storage` and it was detected.

To make the changes permanent, I edited the file `/etc/modules` as root and added the line `usb-storage`

My file now looks like this:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

usb_storage
lp
```

Source: [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1923944)

Comment: I am curious whether you think this could also solve my former problem described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/521559/usb-sticks-not-accessible-system-hangs-at-shut-down-related-older-hardware). If yes, I would like to give it a try and install Lubuntu 14.04 once more on my laptop. Thanks for your answer in advance!

Comment: @Rantanplan Just try it and see, you never know.

Comment: The command worked for me. But i did have that line inside my /etc/modules

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with the ehci / high speed USB 3.0 modules in the kernel.  I've read about this problem with multiple distributions and kernels, and on occasion I read that it had been patched.  Early logs of the problem indicated that the kernel would not allocate enough power to deal with the new demands of the high speed USB, which might explain why it works in host mode (because the kernel didn't get a chance to limit the amount of power allocated), as well as on Windows, but not in Ubuntu.

I have also read that, despite the insufficient power allocation, if you leave the USB stick plugged in for anywhere from 5-15 minutes, it will eventually get prioritized enough to be recognized and mounted.

I'll follow up later with some links, very curious to see how this turns out.

*edit:* Alternatively it could be a problem with FUSE.  Have you tried mounting it from the command line directly, rather than letting FUSE try and fail repeatedly to automount?

*edit 2:* Here is a compilation of other instances of the same problem on varying kernels at varying times.  It seems to be a regression which keeps appearing in the later kernels just as it is resolved in the originally problematic ones.  In each case this was a blkid/udev failure/timeout, and in each case the culprit was a USB 3.0 device being handled by ehci/some variant thereof, and in each case the device is ultimately recognized after a long string of timeouts.  In all of the reported instances, forcefully mounting the device with `sudo mount` was successful, though this may be a fluke.

Worth noting, by the way, is that a kernel downgrade will resolve the issue.  The latest release I saw mentioned as working smoothly was 3.10.7, and before that most people were only successful at <3.10.

So, without further adieu, your evidence:

[Ubuntu 13.04 Does not recognize USB Drives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88440/ubuntu-13-04-does-not-recognize-usb-drive)

[Can't mount specific usb device after kernel upgrade](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1308466)

[USB device constantly being reset](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181368)

[Current Kernel causes blkid USB error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2164982)

[Selective Blindness to Certain USB Devices](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=293065)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm having a problem with Huawei modem not being detected - in the sense that when you plug it in USB, there are _no_ messages whatsoever in dmesg/syslog... Also here, its an older USB modem, and plugged into USB 3 port... and indeed, if I wait 5-10 minutes, then eventually there are messages in syslog, and the device gets recognized... Wish there was something that could force probing on usb buses...

Comment: I'd like to confirm that the Sandisk detection issue in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with FAT32-formatted Cruzer  Glide USB drives, while I don't seem to have problems with EXT4-formatted USB drives (yet, anyway, not completely sure.) Additionally the "modprobe usb-storage" fix does not work.  uname -a:  Linux HP-Pavilion-dv6 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  A cold reboot allows detection ONCE, then /dev/sdb disappears again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may be a Linux driver problem, as your syslog does not report what mine does when I insert a USB disk. Specifically, it is missing the line ".... usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected" immediately after `... not an MTP device` (which it's normal to see, btw). The fact that it works in a live session would back this up. Maybe your installed system has not updated the driver correctly but the driver on a live system is later, and functional.

You can also chat with Sandisk online for free [here](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/utils/chat) Monday - Friday:  08:00 AM - 07:00 PM PDT . I did this recently over issues with my Sandisk SSD. Despite my using Linux, they were very helpful and solved my problem. There are issues with their drives not being recognised under some circumstances.

Comment: I have a similar problem described [here on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/521559/usb-sticks-not-accessible-system-hangs-at-shut-down-related-older-hardware), but there, syslog always shows some lines as `... USB Mass Storage device detected`. Do you think the same solution as @Parto would work here, too? Thanks for a hint!

Comment: I cannot say for sure but I'd certainly try it.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like a driver issue. You could try:

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

Also, could you consider if the drive is old - it may be on it's way out.

Comment: Installed them and restarted my system - still no good.

Comment: -1. Very unlikely, because the "was not an MTP device" triggers on every USB device you attach which isn't an MTP device. Installing MTP software doesn't make it one.

Comment: Did you try to mount manually? mount -t vfat -o rw,nosuid,nodev,quiet,shortname=mixed,uid=1001,gid=100,umask=077,iocharset=utf8 /dev/sda1 /mnt/usbstick

Comment: Alternatively, will have to try to create some udev rules