# USB device not mounting in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount

When I do

```
lsblk
```

This is what I see...

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  99.5G  0 part /media/archisman/Windows
├─sda3   8:3    0 335.8G  0 part /media/archisman/DINDA
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0    30G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1  14.7G  0 disk
```

That sdb is my USB device.

But then I cannot see the device in my file manager.

Somebody please help, I am new to Linux.

Comment: Maybe this can help --> http://askubuntu.com/questions/522515/sandisk-usb-not-detected-by-ubuntu-14-04-but-detected-by-windows-7

Comment: @Parto It did not.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS file system is not supported in Linux 
Try formatting your USB drive with a fat filesystem 
Then it will automatically get mounted

Comment: And how can i do that?