# Vantec NexStar-3 external hard drive won't mount on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, external-hdd

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.05 on a Dell XPS 15.  I have a Vantec NexStar-3 external hard drive enclosure with USB 2.0 output.  When I power up the external HD, the blue Vantec logo turns on and starts blinking.

I've successfully mounted this thing in the past.  However, now when I plug the Vantec's USB cable into my laptop, the drive does not automount, and I get the following message in syslog:

```
kernel: [  430.179180] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
kernel: [  430.195322] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=163e
kernel: [  430.195334] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 16: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3"
mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 16 was not an MTP device
```

lsusb shows the device as "Initio Corporation:"

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 06cb:0ac3 Synaptics, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 13fd:163e Initio Corporation
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 045e:000b Microsoft Corp. Natural Keyboard Elite
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0557:7000 ATEN International Co., Ltd Hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0bda:573c Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Other posts suggested adding a line with the vendor and product ids to /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules.  When I do this, I get the following error dialog:

[image]

Is there anything else I can try to make this external HD enclosure work?

Comment: Does this help at all http://askubuntu.com/questions/522515/sandisk-usb-not-detected-by-ubuntu-14-04-but-detected-by-windows-7

Comment: Well a HDD isn't a MTP device, but your computer seams to think it is. You should play a bit around with your udev rules and try to disable the rule that's causing the problem.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Thanks for the link, but loading the usb_storage module didn't help either.